# html body onload does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple javascript code, but it does not work. My code is :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript</title>
<script>    
var target;
var guess_input;
var guesses = 0;
var finished = false;
var colors = ["black","blue","green","purple","red","white","yellow"];



        function do(){


            var random = Math.random();
            var index = Math.floor(random * 7);
            target = colors[index];
            while(!finished){
                guess_input = prompt("I am thinking of a color : black, blue, green, purple, red, white \n\n" + "What color am i thinking of?");
                guesses++;
                finished = check();    
            }
            var myBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            myBody.style.background = target;
        }

        function check(){
            if (guess_input > target){
                alert("your color is alphabetically higher than mine");
                return false;
            }

            if (guess_input < target){
                alert("your color is alphabetically lower than mine");
                return false;
            }

            if (guess_input == target){
                alert("your color is correct! it tooks you" + guesses "guesses to finish the game!");
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert("Sorry, I do not recoginize your color");
                return false;
            }
</script>
</head>
    <body onload = "do()">

    </body>

</html>
```

The error message is : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token do
part2.html:53 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ), which is "function do()", so what is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: rename your function do and try it again. this might be a keyword problem.

Comment: It is indeed a keyword problem. There's something called `do {} while ()` in javascript, and using `do` as a function name conflicts with that, and `do` is as such a **reserved keyword** that can not be used as names for functions, variables etc.

Answer (score 0):

you missing close parentheses for function check and change do function name to other for example doSomething

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript</title>
    <script>    
    var target;
    var guess_input;
    var guesses = 0;
    var finished = false;
    var colors = ["black","blue","green","purple","red","white","yellow"];
            function doSomething(){


                var random = Math.random();
                var index = Math.floor(random * 7);
                target = colors[index];
                while(!finished){
                    guess_input = prompt("I am thinking of a color : black, blue, green, purple, red, white \n\n" + "What color am i thinking of?");
                    guesses++;
                    finished = check();    
                }
                var myBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
                myBody.style.background = target;
            }

            function check(){
                if (guess_input > target){
                    alert("your color is alphabetically higher than mine");
                    return false;
                }

                if (guess_input < target){
                    alert("your color is alphabetically lower than mine");
                    return false;
                }

                if (guess_input == target){
                    alert("your color is correct! it tooks you" + guesses "guesses to finish the game!");
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Sorry, I do not recoginize your color");
                    return false;
                }
            }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="doSomething()">

    </body>

    </html>
```